Infinite category structure on SCRing and 'space of commutative squares' in SCRing
When I read this paper 'virtual cartier divisors and blow ups', I often meet with such phrase like 'mapping space of infinite category $SCRing_{A}$'. See lemma 2.3.5 in the above paper: $Map_{SCRing_{A}}(A//(f_{1},\cdots,f_{n},B)\cong \prod_{1\leq i\leq n}Maps_{B}(f_{i}',0)$ where $A//(f_{1},\cdots,f_{n})$ is the derived tensor product:

and $f_{i}'$ is the image of $f_{i}$ under the structure map of $B$ as $A$ algebra.
Then the author considers the 'space of commutative squares' as the mapping space
$Map_{SCRing_{A}}(A//(f_{1},\cdots,f_{n}),B)$.

Actually this diagram is in the 'homotopy' sense, so each square corresponds to an identification between the image of $(f_{1},\cdots,f_{n})$ and $(0,\cdots,0)$, which corresponds to a point in $\prod_{1\leq i\leq n}Maps_{B}(f_{i}',0)$
Question 1: What is the infinite category structure on $SCRing_{A}=Fun(\triangle^{op},CRing_{A})$?
As far as I have known, category $SCRing_{A}$ can be viewed as a simplicial enriched category by the simplicial Hom set $\underline{Hom}$. And taking the simplicial nerve of the cofibrant objects leads to the infinite category structure (weak Kan complex). I feel like this construction is not easy to handle with and obviously the rings we are faced with here may not be all cofibrant, so is there any other way to understand the infinite category structure on $SCRing_{A}$, or more generally, $SCRing$.
Question 2: Following the Question 1, how do we understand the 'mapping space' between two simplicial rings without taking cofibrant replacement in the infinite category $SCRing_{A}$?
Considering that I still can't understand what the infinite category structure on the category of simplicial rings is, so I have no idea of what this space is, but I feel like the 'point' in this space indeed corresponds to a commutative square as above, but how can I see that the mapping space is identified with the 'space of commutative diagrams', the latter space, I guess is some Kan complex with 1-morphism as the morphism between two commutative squares (like some cubic diagram), but there is no clue that such two space is the same space.
So what is the space(simplicial) structure on the collection of commutative squares?
Question 3: So, if we just admit that the $Maps_{SCRing_{A}}(A//(f_{1},\cdots,f_{n}),B)$ is the 'space of commutative diagrams' with certain 'space structure', then how to prove the space isomorphism with $\prod_{i} Maps_{B}(f_{i}',0)$?
In my eyes, the mapping space $Maps_{B}(f_{i}',0)$ has a clear space(Kan complex) structure: it consists of 'points' as the 1-morphisms in $B$ connecting $f_{i}'$ and $0$, while higher morphism encodes the information about composition of such 1-morphisms.
If we want to show the isomorphism between mapping spaces, then we not only deal with the 'points', we also should deal with the higher information. But for 'the space of commutative squares', I believe there is higher information about this space, how do we describe them to prove space isomorphism?
It seems that the proof is done by only considering the 'point' of this mapping space, there is no higher information involved.  I can't understand this 'set-like' bijective correspondence leads to the isomorphism of spaces.
Question 4: I see there are also phrases like 'map between mapping spaces is invertible' like lemma 3.2.8, I just want to ask whether 'invertible ' means exactly isomorphism between spaces or some equivalence in the weaker sense?

Question 1. In the paper that you linked, $\mathrm{SCRing}$ is already defined to be an $\infty$-category, namely the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathscr{T},\mathrm{Spc})$, where $\mathscr{T}$ is the $1$-category associated to the Lawvere theory for commutative rings (i.e. $\mathscr{T}$ is the opposite of the full subcategory of $\mathrm{CRing}$ on the rings $\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$ for $n\geq 0$), $\mathrm{Spc}$ is the $\infty$-category of spaces, and $\mathrm{Fun}^\times(-,-)$ is the full sub(-$\infty$-)category of $\mathrm{Fun}(-,-)$ on functors that preserve finite products. Given any object $A\in\mathrm{SCRing}$, we can then take $\mathrm{SCRing}_A$ to be the full subcategory of $\mathrm{Fun}([1],\mathrm{SCRing})$ (where $[1]$ is the walking arrow category $0\to 1$) on those functors $F$ that satisfy $F(0)\simeq A$.
We can also give a model-categorical presentation of this, along the lines of the functor category you wrote down: because $\mathrm{CRing}\simeq\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathscr{T},\mathrm{Set})$, there is a canonical equivalence
$$
\mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^\mathrm{op},\mathrm{CRing})\simeq\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathscr{T},\mathrm{sSet}),
$$
and on the latter category we know how to define a model structure: a map $f\colon A\to B$ in this category is a weak equivalence (resp. a fibration) if it is a Kan weak equivalence (resp. Kan fibration) on the underlying simplicial sets (after forgetting the commutative ring structure). Once we have a model structure, there are several equivalent ways of producing an underlying $\infty$-category, see e.g. my answer here. I want to stress that we do not take the simplicial nerve $N\colon\mathrm{Cat}\to\mathrm{sSet}$ of the category of cofibrant-fibrant objects of $\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathscr{T},\mathrm{sSet})$. This will indeed result in a quasicategory, but it will just be the $1$-category $\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathscr{T},\mathrm{sSet})$, forgetting any homotopical structure that we put on it via our weak equivalences.
Question 2. If you define $\mathrm{SCRing}$ in the purely $\infty$-categorical manner, then there is a formula for its mapping spaces in terms of some end, mimicking the formula we have for hom sets in $\mathrm{CRing}$ in terms of hom sets of underlying sets. If you prefer the model-categorical presentation but do not want to compute cofibrant replacements, then we can exploit that all objects in $\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathscr{T},\mathrm{sSet})$ are fibrant, which means that $\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathscr{T},\mathrm{sSet})$ also carries the structure of a fibration category. You can compute the mapping spaces of the underlying $\infty$-category then also as the nerve of a ''category of zig-zags'', as for instance described in Theorem 3.61 in Nikolaus-Schreiber-Stevenson Principal $\infty$-bundles - Presentations (arXiv link). The advantage is that you don't need cofibrant replacements. The disadvantage is that your resulting simplicial set is very big and may not be easy to analyze effectively.
Question 2.5. Given an $\infty$-category $\mathscr{C}$, the space of commutative squares in $\mathscr{C}$ is the $\infty$-groupoid $\mathrm{Fun}([1]\times[1],\mathscr{C})^\simeq$, where $\mathscr{D}^\simeq$ is the core of an $\infty$-category $\mathscr{D}$. In our case, we want to fix certain corners and morphisms in the square. This data is the functor $F\colon(01\leftarrow 00\to 10)\to\mathrm{SCRing}$ given by $A\leftarrow\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots, T_n]\to\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/(T_1,\ldots,T_n)$. Hence, the space of commutative squares
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n]@>>> \mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/(T_1,\ldots,T_n)\\
@V{T_i\mapsto f_i}VV @VVV\\
A @>>> B
\end{CD}
$$
(where $B$ is allowed to change among different squares) is the space
$$
\mathrm{Fun}([1]\times[1],\mathrm{SCRing})^\simeq\times_{\mathrm{restriction},\;\mathrm{Fun}((01\leftarrow 00\to 10), \mathrm{SCRing})^\simeq,\;F} *
$$
where $*$ is a contractible space (and this fiber product is a homotopy fiber product, that is, a fiber product in the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{Spc}$). If we additionally want the bottom right corner of the square to be fixed on the object $B$, we look at the diagram shape $\mathsf{C}$ given by
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
00 @>>> 10\\
@VVV \\
01 &&11
\end{CD}
$$
Then our fixed data is the functor $G\colon\mathsf{C}\to\mathrm{SCRing}$ given by
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n]@>>> \mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/(T_1,\ldots,T_n)\\
@V{T_i\mapsto f_i}VV\\
A && B
\end{CD}
$$
and the space of commutative squares completing the above diagram (with $B$ fixed this time) is the space
$$
\mathrm{Fun}([1]\times[1],\mathrm{SCRing})^\simeq\times_{\mathrm{restriction},\;\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{C}, \mathrm{SCRing})^\simeq,\;G} *.
$$
It is now a fair question how this relates to the space $\mathrm{SCRing}(A//(f_1,\ldots,f_n),B)$. However, since $A//(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ is defined to be the colimit of $F$, the equivalence
$$
\mathrm{Fun}([1]\times[1],\mathrm{SCRing})^\simeq\times_{\mathrm{restriction},\;\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{C}, \mathrm{SCRing})^\simeq,\;G} *\simeq\mathrm{SCRing}(A//(f_1,\ldots,f_n),B)
$$
is the universal property of the pushout. One way to be extra convinced of this is believing there is an equivalence
$$
\mathrm{Fun}([1]\times[1],\mathrm{SCRing})^\simeq\times_{\mathrm{restriction},\;\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{C}, \mathrm{SCRing})^\simeq,\;G} *\\
\simeq \mathrm{SCRing}(\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/(T_1,\ldots,T_n),B)\times_{\mathrm{SCRing}(\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n],B)}\mathrm{SCRing}(A,B).
$$
This is proven using some standard (if you're used to higher category theory) techniques. You for instance use that $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{E}\sqcup_\mathcal{F}\mathcal{G},\mathrm{SCRing})\simeq\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{E},\mathrm{SCRing})\times_{\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{F},\mathrm{SCRing})}\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{G},\mathrm{SCRing})$, and that the mapping space is defined as a pullback
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{SCRing}(X,Y) @>>> \mathrm{Fun}([1],\mathrm{SCRing})^\simeq\\
@VVV @VVV\\
* @>{(X,Y)}>> \mathrm{Fun}([0]\sqcup[0], \mathrm{SCRing})^\simeq
\end{CD}
$$
(Note that we could also have used $\mathrm{Fun}([1],\mathrm{SCRing})$ and $\mathrm{Fun}([0]\sqcup[0],\mathrm{SCRing})$ in the pullback square above and still end up with the same pullback, which is why for our purposes, it does not matter if we started with the space of commutative squares, or all of the $\infty$-category of commutative squares: in the end, we still end up with the same space once we start fixing the things we want to fix (including $B$).)
Question 3. There is a quick way of seeing this if we just work $\infty$-categorically and take $\mathrm{SCRing}$ to be $\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathscr{T},\mathrm{Spc})$. Namely, every object in $\mathscr{T}$ defines via the Yoneda embedding an object of $\mathrm{SCRing}$, so in particular $\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n]\in\mathscr{T}$ can be regarded as an object of $\mathrm{SCRing}$. However, this object in $\mathscr{T}$ is the $n$-fold product of $\mathbb{Z}[T]$ in $\mathscr{T}$, so given any $B\in\mathrm{SCRing}$, we have
$$
\mathrm{SCRing}(\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n],B)\simeq B(\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n])\simeq \prod_{i=1}^n B(\mathbb{Z}[T]),
$$
where the first equivalence is the Yoneda lemma, and the second follows as $B\colon\mathscr{T}\to\mathrm{Spc}$ preserves products. Note that $B(\mathbb{Z}[T])$ is the underlying space of $B$, a concept we already encountered in Question $1$, when talking about the model categorical presentation of $\mathrm{SCRing}$ (namely, when we talked about the simplicial set underlying a simplicial commutative ring). We will write $|B|$ for this underlying space.
A commutative square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n]@>>> \mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/(T_1,\ldots,T_n)\\
@V{T_i\mapsto f_i}VV @VVV\\
A @>>> B
\end{CD}
$$
is the data of two maps $\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n]\to B$ and a homotopy between them. Going down and then to the right, we get the map $G_1$ classified in the above sense by the $n$ elements $f'_1,\ldots,f'_n\in|B|$. Going to the right first and then down, we get the map $G_2$ classified by the $n$ elements $0,\ldots,0\in|B|$. A homotopy between these two maps is a path in the mapping space $\mathrm{SCRing}(\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n],B)$. As such, the space of commutative squares as above is equivalent to the space
$$
\mathrm{map}_{\mathrm{SCRing}(\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n],B)}(G_1,G_2).
$$
Since $\mathrm{SCRing}(\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\ldots,T_n],B)\simeq|B|^n$, under which $G_1$ becomes $(f'_1,\ldots,f'_n)$ and $G_2$ becomes $(0,\ldots,0)$, this space is equivalent to the space
$$
\mathrm{map}_{|B|^n}((f'_1,\ldots,f'_n),(0,\ldots0)).
$$
Now, a path in $|B|^n$ consists of $n$ individual paths in $|B|$. More formally, taking mapping spaces is a right adjoint functor and hence commutes with limits. As such,
$$
\mathrm{map}_{|B|^n}((f'_1,\ldots,f'_n),(0,\ldots0))\simeq\mathrm{map}_{|B|}(f'_1,0)\times\ldots\times\mathrm{map}_{|B|}(f'_n,0).
$$
This establishes the equivalence we were after.
Note that it indeed very much looks like we are only checking things on points. But the $\infty$-categorical universal properties that we use make sure that our arguments automatically give equivalences on the whole space, and not only a bijection on the $\pi_0$ of our spaces.
Question 4. When these authors talk about spaces, they mean objects of the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{Spc}$ of spaces. As such, invertible maps are the equivalences of this $\infty$-category. Whether or not you call that an isomorphism is up to you. In a model-categorical presentation of $\mathrm{Spc}$, such as $\mathrm{sSet}$ or $\mathrm{Top}$, these equivalences of spaces are not modelled by isomorphisms of simplicial sets or topological spaces, but rather by weak homotopy equivalences. In particular, if you think about mapping spaces as Kan complexes, then an invertible map of spaces corresponds to a homotopy equivalence between Kan complexes.

Thank you so much for your answer! I just want to ask that under your definition of 'space of commutative diagrams', how do we just directly using universal property of $A//(f_{1},\cdots,f_{n})$ as homotopy limit? As far as I learn in your another answer, the universal property can be translated into the invertible map $Map(A//(f_{1},\cdots,f_{n}),B)\cong Map(A,B)\times_{Map(Z[T_{1},\cdots,T_{n}],B)} Map(Z[T_{1},\cdots,T_{n}],B)$. There seems to be a gap between this and space of diagrams.

In your answers for Question 3 and Question 4, I just realize that the proposition can be directly proved without using 'this space of diagrams'. So is this definition of 'space of commutative diagrams' some frequently used thing? I just get confused why we take the underlying infinite groupoid of the infinite category $Fun([1]\times [1],C)$? I understand we get a 'space', but why should we need the collection of commutative diagrams to shape a 'space', instead of just an infinite category? Great thanks for any perspectives on this!

Regarding your first comment: thank you for spotting a mistake! I forgot to fix the object $B$ in the space of squares. I edited it now and added some explanation. In summary, if you call $X$ the space of commutative squares in which you fix the left and top maps and fix the object $B$ in the right bottom corner, then $X$ is equivalent to this homotopy pullback of mapping spaces that you mentioned. I edited in some statements that are used to prove this, but I did not write out the proof itself. Let me know if this is okay for you.

Regarding whether to use $\mathrm{Fun}([1]\times[1],C)$ or $\mathrm{Fun}([1]\times[1],C)^\simeq$: in this case it does not actually matter, because once we start fixing the parts of the square that we want fixed (including $B$), we will end up with the same space no matter which of the two collections of commutative squares we started with. I used the space of commutative squares, and not all of the $\infty$-category, because  the paper you mentioned talked about the space of squares. The $\infty$-category contains more information and it is more standard to use that.

It holds that $\mathrm{Fun}([1]\times[1],C)^\simeq$ is the mapping space $\mathrm{Cat}\infty([1]\times[1],C)$ in the $(\infty,1)$-category of $(\infty,1)$-categories $\mathrm{Cat}\infty$, so it is sometimes easier to say something about this space of commutative squares because you only have to study an $(\infty,1)$-category $\mathrm{Cat}\infty$. On the other hand, $\mathrm{Fun}([1]\times[1],C)$ is the mapping $(\infty,1)$-category $\mathrm{Cat}\infty^{(2)}([1]\times[1],C)$ of the $(\infty,2)$-category $\mathrm{Cat}_\infty^{(2)}$ of $(\infty,1)$-categories.
